# How to make HttpResponse work much faster?

Tags: java, android, http, httpresponse

I am working on a project in which I have to get 4096 bytes of data to server from "server" between every 1-millisecond to 10-millisecond. But it's taking too much time i.e around 300ms - 700ms which causes my application to lose data.

I am using below snippet

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.40/ping");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The HttpResponse is only taking too much time i.e around 300ms - 700ms.

**How I can get response faster?**

**Instead of this what else I can use to get a response from server faster then this?**

I have done some research, gone through other ways like `DataOutputStream` and `ByteOutputStream` but no use of this, it also taking too much time then `HttpResponse`.

Comment: This might be a latency issue rather than a programming issue :(

Comment: Unless the server that you are accessing is on your local network, you will probably never be able to get that speed.

Comment: what is the ping time? How long does curl take to fetch the same resource, e.g. `time curl -i 'http://www.my_site.com"`?

Comment: @Kevin, I agree, if ping time is too long not many things can help to speed it up

Comment: @Kevin I ll check and let u know..

Comment: There's code optimisations, such as not recreating the `HttpClient` and `HttpGet` every time. But, what might be better would be to cache the data on the server, so when you ask for data it feeds you 4K x number of ms since last call. It might also be faster to use a raw socket and dump all the HTTP overhead, if you really need to access every few milliseconds.

Comment: @Kevin it showing this real - 0m0.009s,user - 0m0.004s,sys - 0m0.004s when I used `time curl -i 'http://www.my_site.com"`

Comment: @KenY-N , He is using HttpPost MEthod not Get

Comment: @KenY-N , sorry I am uising HttpPost, Mistakenly wrote HttpGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You are recreating a connection every time.

You need to hold a persistent connection with the server. Try creating a persistent http connection.

If that doesn't work you can try sending raw udp packets (or anything else). It will be harder but it will take less time.

Comment: can you give me a link that have persistent connection example or some code

Answer (score 4):

Before you can make the responses faster, you are going to need to investigate and understand why they are currently taking a long time.  Roughly speaking, it could be:

- the client side taking a long time to create the request and/or preocess the result (seems unlikely ...)
- a slow android network protocol stack
- a problem with your local networking (e.g. WiFi) or your telecoms provider
- a congested / overloaded server or server-side network, or
- something pessimal in the server implementation.

Do things like:

- try the request from a web browser on a conventional PC and use the browser's web-developer stuff to try to tease out whether/why the request is taking a long time ...
- look in the server-side logs and/or monitoring for request load and timing information
- *other suggestions please*

Implementing SPDY *might* help, but it is *unlikely* to change response times in the order of 500ms to a couple of tens of milliseconds.  The problem seems more fundamental than "HTTP is old and slow".  And the same reasoning applies to all of the other suggestions that people have made.

Comment: client side it taking almost 10ms to connect with server, but at the time of response between 100ms - 200ms is taking. I am using LAN to perform this task. On server data receives and sends to other part and data removed from server after sent so no overload on that. Server implementation is perfect. It taking time due to everytime establishment of connection. Now I am trying to perform persistent connection. But dont know how to do that. Can you help me out or any       solution or idea how to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPDY](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/) protocol. This would improve your response time.

I think in your case you can use websockets so that you would not have to create a connection each time and the live connection is available every time.

Comment: Is SPDY runnign only on SSL or it is possible to use it over HTTP. What will happen, when we use an self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes SPDY runs only on SSL. I think as along as it runs on HTTPS SPDY would work.

Answer (score 0):

@sheldonCooper answer is right if the server enables SPDY. Also you can add Gzip compression. It has been added to all requests after GingerBread but you could add it for former SDK versions : http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html